# Ask what to do when dragging & dropping a file in file managers other than Dolphin

Tags: symlink, file-copy, file-manager, move, dolphin

Dolphin file manager is showing a list of options when dragging & dropping a file (copy/move/create link).

Can the same options be made available in other file managers?

Answer (score 0):

### PCManFM

In *Edit - Preferences - General* - "Default drop action" - change to "Ask".

[image]

When dropping the file the menu appears.

[image]

Tested in version 1.3.1.

---

### PCManFM-qt

**While dragging the file, right-click** and the menu should appear. (It appears even within the same location, but that is buggy.)

[image]

Tested with v. 0.14.1.